# Weird behavior while using Subjects/event emitters in services for cross component communication in angular?

Tags: angular, observable, behaviorsubject, subject

I want to understand how observable, subjects and behavior subject work(have read a lot of articles , watched a lot of videos but its still not clear to me as i have failed to explain this behavior) so i created this simple example and got an unexpected behavior.
I have two components a **parent component** and a **child component**.

The parent component displays a list of having names of photos with buttons to show details. When this button is clicked it will take us into the child component where i wish to display the single photo along with the details. So, this is the idea.

I have used a service where i have a subject. Now whenever the button in the parent component is clicked , I am emitting a value from the subject. I want to catch this value in my child component, so I am subscribing to it.

There is a weird behavior--
For the first click i do not see any data in my child component.
Second click a single value in child component.
Third click two values in child component,
and so on....

Here are my components--

**parent.component.ts**

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  photoList = [
    {
      albumId: 1,
      id: 1,
      title: "accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt",
      url: "https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952",
      thumbnailUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952",
    },
    {
      albumId: 1,
      id: 2,
      title: "reprehenderit est deserunt velit ipsam",
      url: "https://via.placeholder.com/600/771796",
      thumbnailUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/150/771796",
    },
    {
      albumId: 1,
      id: 3,
      title: "officia porro iure quia iusto qui ipsa ut modi",
      url: "https://via.placeholder.com/600/24f355",
      thumbnailUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/150/24f355",
    },
  ];
  constructor(private _talkService: TalkService, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  displayName(id, url, thumbnailUrl) {
    console.log({ id, url, thumbnailUrl });

    //this._talkService.talk.emit({ url, thumbnailUrl });
    this._talkService.talk.next({ id, url, thumbnailUrl });
    this.router.navigate(["/photo"]);
  }
}
```

**child.component.ts**

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private _talkService: TalkService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("child component created");
    this._talkService.talk.subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

**talk.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class TalkService {
  // talk = new EventEmitter();
  talk = new Subject();
  constructor() {}
}
```

**Output console logs**

[image: App with console logs]

I have used these three--

Event Emitters-->same behavior as described
Subjects-->same behavior as described
Behavior Subjects--> I get the first value as well(As it helps us to get the  the previously emitted value, that part I understand). A detailed explanation here is also welcome.

I was expecting a single value on each click, but this is not the case. Can someone please explain me the behavior. It must be the way observable work and I am not able to get it.

**Here is the link to my github repo--**

[source code github](https://github.com/Arpan619Banerjee/observabels_subjects)

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: i dn t know how to do that..i can share the git hub repo link if that can help...

Comment: google angular stackblitz, open first link, click on fork, do your code, save your code, click on share, send the first link from share window.

Comment: its not working, it says unable to import my components and src package nt found..i have shared the link to my gitub repo, u can fork it and try its a small piece of code. Thanks.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a classic memory leak. Every time you subscribe to `talkService.talk` you are creating a subscription that will only get cleaned after it is unsubscribed. So even though the Child components seem like they're being destroyed when you go back to the parent component, the subscription still exists and is doing the console log every time the `talk` subject emits a new value. You should unsubscribe when the Child component gets destroyed. An easy way of making sure subscriptions are unsubscribed is to use the [`async`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) pipe in the html template.

**child.component.ts**

```js
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  data$: Observable<any> = this.talkService.talk;

  constructor(private talkService: TalkService) {}
}
```

**child.component.html**

```html
<pre>{{ data$ | async }}</pre>
```

Also, you can switch back to using `BehaviorSubject` since the child component will be subscribing to `talk` after the value is emitted from the parent component.

Comment: Makes sense, but I was wondering, that once I subscribe to an event and consume the data how that data is still available when I subscribe to another click event on the same button,understand what I am trying to say?Like how does it work, the subject stores all the event values always?

Comment: I tried using the code u gave, the async pipe thing, it didn t work, i am getting the same behavior. Is it working for you?

Comment: Subjects don't really 'store' values, they emit values. They are a type of observable that you can _subscribe_ to, and you handle values emitted from subjects with these subscriptions. Yes it is working for me, you probably did not remove the subscription in your child component. Check this stackblitz. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vrcgkp

Comment: Can u pls share the stackblitz link again, tha above link is not working anymore

Comment: It would probably be better if you created a stackblitz with your issue so you can manage and own it.